# iPad video player with playback speed control

Tags: video, media-player, ipad-app

I need some free video player which would allow to view video on speed **more than 2x**.

I found OPlayerHD Lite for video and Snippz for youtube, but in both maximal speed is 2x.

On Windows I'm using GOM Player and speed limit is 4x. Is there something like that for iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually OPlayerHD Lite supports spped up to 4x for some kind of files. It marks them via lightning sign. At least it does for h264 codec in avi.

[image: Screenshot]